Runing WebDriverIo Test on Electron Application in Dev Mode
I am trying to use wdio for my electron project, its working very well when running it on the build (release/win-unpacked/)
but when I set the configuration file to use it directly in dev mode
       capabilities: [{
        browserName: 'electron',
        // Electron service options
        // see https://webdriver.io/docs/desktop-testing/electron/configuration/#service-options
        'wdio:electronServiceOptions': {
            // custom application args
            appBinaryPath: `${process.cwd()}/node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe`,
            appArgs: [`app=${process.cwd()}/.`]
        },
    }],

I get an error, Electron is running but I am getting:

Cannot find module "myprojectPath/node_modules/electron/main"

I am using Electron 28, "wdio-electron-service": "6.6.1",  "@wdio/cli": "8.39.0",
I tried all possible combination for the appArgs without success.
for example appArgs: ['app=.']
When i try to run the command ./node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe . or ./node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe --app=. from my project root folder its working well and running my application.
